# Drawing "blobs"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw diagrams representing sets as `blobs` using tikz, that is an object having no distinct shape (this is one definition of `blob`.) It doesn't have to be tikz specifically : any solution is welcome, it just happens to be the only way I am aware of to draw diagrams in LaTeX. Also, I have to be able to fit the drawings in `commutative diagrams` containing standard arrows etc, which is why I felt compelled to use tikz.

At any rate, I would like to create drawings that look like the one below

[image: Screen shot]

How do I create these "generic shapes"?

Here's a drawing more in line with the result I want to achieve.

[image: Screen shot]

The bent line in `X` is supposed to represent the inverse image under the map `f` of the point drawn in `f(X)`, and the two points on it are the images of the two points on the left under the map `alpha`.

[Related Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54985/amoeba-shape-with-tikz).

Comment: Perhaps related, specially if you want random blobs: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35534/tips-for-creating-semi-random-blob-in-tikz, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121388/random-ink-blotches-from-tikz/121408#121408

Comment: Maybe also related: [Can I make coordinate plot more smooth?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140916/5645)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image]

This is a `MWE` with the `Asymptote`,

```
// blobs.asy :
//
size(7cm);

import graph;
import patterns;

import fontsize;
defaultpen(fontsize(9pt));

texpreamble("\usepackage{lmodern}");

pen hatchPen=orange+0.4bp;
pen borderPen=deepblue+1bp;
pen arrPen=red+1bp;
pen areaBG=palegreen;

pair[] dots={
(25,280),
(60,280),
(25,140),
};

pair star=(60,137);

guide[] arrows={(25,265)--(25,160),
(60,265){dir(-90)}..(60,200)..(40,160),
};

guide[] markedArrows={
(150,280)--(200,280),
(150,140)--(200,140),
(360,240)--(360,200),
};

pair[] xArea={
(409,257),
(415,272),
(400,289),
(383,291),
(367,292),
(358,300),
(355,307),
(344,317),
(330,317),
(320,312),
(311,319),
(303,308),
(302,303),
(306,298),
(306,287),
(312,277),
(319,269),
(330,267),
(346,260),
(366,259),
};

pair[] xAreaInside={
(341,272),
(332,282),
(333,301),
(339,312),
(385,270),
};


pair[] yArea={
(379,35),
(398,36),
(422,39),
(453,52),
(468,63),
(484,86),
(478,107),
(453,110),
(426,111),
(393,129),
(361,149),
(349,157),
(335,157),
(323,173),
(303,173),
(283,153),
(267,134),
(266,113),
(280,100),
(297,93),
(313,82),
(329,64),
(341,45),
};


pair[] smallShArea={
(400,41),
(403,46),
(399,51),
(406,58),
(408,66),
(398,63),
(387,59),
(380,57),
(369,62),
(360,57),
(366,48),
(376,46),
(384,48),
};

pair[] bigShArea={
(380,74),
(390,83),
(396,99),
(389,111),
(376,115),
(358,123),
(340,130),
(326,144),
(307,151),
(295,146),
(295,140),
(299,129),
(304,119),
(321,116),
(334,107),
(348,87),
};


pair[] yAreaInside={
(315,136),
(370,97),
(436,85),
(460,82),
};

dot(dots,UnFill);

draw(arrows[0],arrPen,Arrow(HookHead,size=4));
draw(arrows[1],arrPen,Arrow(HookHead,size=4));


for(int i=0;i<markedArrows.length;++i){
  draw(markedArrows[i],arrPen,Arrow(HookHead,size=4));
}

filldraw(graph(xArea,operator..)..cycle,areaBG,borderPen);
draw(graph(xAreaInside[0:4],operator..),borderPen);

dot(xAreaInside[1:3],UnFill);
label("$X$",xAreaInside[4]);

filldraw(graph(yArea,operator..)..cycle,areaBG,borderPen);

guide gsmallShArea=graph(smallShArea,operator..)..cycle; 
guide gbigShArea=graph(bigShArea,operator..)..cycle; 

add("hatch",hatch(1mm,hatchPen));
fill(gsmallShArea,pattern("hatch"));
fill(gbigShArea,pattern("hatch"));

draw(gsmallShArea,borderPen);
draw(gbigShArea,borderPen);

dot(yAreaInside[0],UnFill);
label("$f(X)$",yAreaInside[1]);
label("*",yAreaInside[2]);
label("Y",yAreaInside[3]);

label("$\alpha$",markedArrows[0],N);
label("$\beta$",markedArrows[1],N);
label("$f$",markedArrows[2],E);

label("*",star);
```

To get a standalone `blobs.pdf`, run `asy -f pdf blobs.asy`, 
it will automatically run `pdflatex` to typeset the labels.

Comment: This is absolutely stunning! Please tell me, how did you produce all the coordinates?

Comment: Also, can the same be done in `tikz`?

Comment: This is my first time using asymptote, do I have to add a preamble to what you wrote? I'm sorry to ask such a basic question, but I have no idea what an `asy` file looks like :(

Comment: Forget about the `asy` question, I got it to work. But please tell me how you produced all of those coordinates!

Comment: @Olivier Bégassat: You can use any digitizer to get coordinates from the sketch, for example [plotdigitizer](http://plotdigitizer.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 11):

This should get you started. You can draw blobs using `tikz` and the `hobby` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%% Blob
\path[draw,use Hobby shortcut,closed=true]
(0,0) .. (.5,1) .. (1,3) .. (.3,4) .. (-1,2) .. (-1,.5);
\begin{scope}[xshift=4cm]
\draw (0,0) to [quick curve through={(0,0) (.5,1) .. (1,3) .. (.3,4) .. (-1,2)}] (0,0) ;
\end{scope}
%% Curvy line using hobby
\path[draw,-stealth,use Hobby shortcut,closed=false]
(-1.5,0) .. (-2.2,-2.2) .. (-2.8,-3);
\draw[xshift=-.5cm,-stealth] (-1.5,0) to [quick curve through={(-2.2,-2.2)}] (-2.8,-3) ;
%% Cury line without hobby
\path[draw,xshift=.5cm]
(-1.5,0) edge[out=-95,in=45,-stealth] (-2.8,-3);
\path[draw,xshift=1cm,-stealth]
(-1.5,0) to[out=-95,in=45] (-2.8,-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The one on the left looks very nice. Can I use the same command without the `closed=true` to draw a generic curvy line?

Comment: Great! I don't know how to install the `hobby` package though. I don't understand the [instructions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86363/where-in-the-world-is-tikzlibraryhobby-code-tex) given here at all, could you please help?

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm using TeXmaker, so I guess the distribution is MikTeX? I use a computer at my university, it runs Linux Mint. Is the package manager something I can acess from the TeXmaker interface?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Texmaker is only an editor. May be this question: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) is useful

Comment: Thanks, how can I find out which distribution I'm using?

Comment: Ok, so I'm using `TeX Live 2009/Debian`